# Function in js or jquery to replace "X" with a random number

Tags: javascript, jquery

example:

```
var = "10XX489X1X2"
```

the function must replace **X** with a random number
(example) : 10(50)4895(1)(9)2

*All numbers must be different*

Comment: first, this should be a string i.e. `"10XX489X1X2"`. Is there a range from which the number should be inserted.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: bro yes it's string just i forgot to put ("")
i want too change X by random number not inserted number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace All occurrences of `X` with a random number (I've taken the range from `1` to `99`). You can do this with the help of [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

```js
var s = "10XX489X1X2";

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

const str = s.replaceAll("X", () => randomIntFromInterval(1, 99));

const num = Number(str);
console.log(num);
```

using `for..of` loop

```js
var s = "10XX489X1X2";

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

let strArr = [];
for (let char of s) {
  if (char === "X") strArr.push(randomIntFromInterval(1, 99));
  else strArr.push(char);
}

const resultStr = strArr.join("");
console.log(resultStr);
```

Comment: what do you mean by `0` at first it disappears?

Comment: got it, You mean if you add `0` at the beginning of the `s`. Since `s` is a string so you can add `0` in the beginning but when you convert it to a number using `Number` or `parseInt` then the `0` is removed from the number. Because `0123` is equal to `123`. If you want to remain to be a string then don't convert it to a number.

Comment: u can make the same function using loop functions ?

Comment: @rick34okod33r-شاروون- edited the answer and the result will be a string. You can convert it into number type using `parseInt` or `Number` if you want.

Comment: bro u can explain to me why u use this 
(max - min + 1) + min

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution should work. It will replace every time there is a 'X' in the original string with the same random number. After that, it will convert the string into a number then print the result.

```
const min = 0;
const max = 9;

let originalNumber = "10XX489X1X2";

originalNumber = Number(originalNumber.replace(/X/g, Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)))

console.log(originalNumber)
```